# How to take User input in one frame and adding it to an arraylist to display on another frame

Tags: java, swing, object, arraylist, jframe

how do you get the User input inside `JTextFeild` and SET/ADD the input to the table in another frame? Student objects are stored in an `ArrayList`. The array list is added to table view and displayed in another frame. `StudentCntl`, `StudentListUI`, `StudentUI` are shown below. StudentListUI(left) StudentUI(right)

[image]

```
public class StudentCntl {

    private static final int STARTING_INDEX_OF_DISPLAY = 0;
    StudentCntl studentCntl;
    StudentList studentList;
    StudentUI studentUI;
    StudentListUI studentListUI;
    StudentTableModel theStudentTable;

    public StudentCntl() {
        studentList = new StudentList();
        theStudentTable = new StudentTableModel(studentList.getStudentList());
        studentUI = new StudentUI(this, STARTING_INDEX_OF_DISPLAY); 
        studentUI.setVisible(true);
        studentListUI = new StudentListUI(this, studentUI);
        studentListUI.setVisible(true);

    }

    public StudentTableModel getStudentTableModel() {
        return theStudentTable;
    }
    Student getStudent(int index) {
         Student student = studentList.getStudentList().get(index);
         return student;
    }
```

---

```
public class StudentUI extends JFrame {

    private int indexOfElementToDisplay;

    private final JTextField firstNameDisplayValue = new JTextField(15);
    private final JTextField lastNameDisplayValue = new JTextField(15);
    private final JTextField gpaDisplayValue = new JTextField(15);

    private JPanel studentPanel;
    private JPanel buttonPanel;
    String[] info = {firstNameDisplayValue.getText(),lastNameDisplayValue.getText(),gpaDisplayValue.getText()};


private final StudentCntl studentCntl;
    public StudentUI(StudentCntl studentCntl, int startingIndexOfDisplay) {
        this.studentCntl = studentCntl;
        indexOfElementToDisplay = startingIndexOfDisplay;
        initComponents();
        setFieldView();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        setTitle("Student Viewer");
        setSize(500, 400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        studentPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 1));
        studentPanel.add(new JLabel("First Name"));
        studentPanel.add(firstNameDisplayValue); 

        studentPanel.add(new JLabel("Last Name"));
        studentPanel.add(lastNameDisplayValue);
        studentPanel.add(new JLabel("GPA"));
        studentPanel.add(gpaDisplayValue);

        buttonPanel = new JPanel(new   FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        JButton nextButton = new JButton("Next");
        JButton previousButton = new JButton("Previous");
        JButton deleteButton = new JButton("Delete");
        JButton newButton = new JButton("New Entry");
        JButton saveButton = new JButton("Save");
        nextButton.addActionListener(e -> showNext(indexOfElementToDisplay));
        buttonPanel.add(nextButton);

        previousButton.addActionListener(e -> showPrevious(indexOfElementToDisplay));
        buttonPanel.add(previousButton);

        deleteButton.addActionListener(e -> showDelete(indexOfElementToDisplay));
        buttonPanel.add(deleteButton);

        saveButton.addActionListener(e -> addToList(info));
        buttonPanel.add(saveButton);

        newButton.addActionListener(e -> showNew());
        buttonPanel.add(newButton);

        setContentPane(new JPanel(new BorderLayout()));
        getContentPane().add(studentPanel,      BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }



    private void setFieldView() {
            firstNameDisplayValue.setText(studentCntl.getStudent(indexOfElementToDisplay).getFirstName());
       lastNameDisplayValue.setText(studentCntl.getStudent(indexOfElementToDisplay).getLastName());
        gpaDisplayValue.setText(Double.toString(studentCntl.getStudent(indexOfElementToDisplay).getGpa()));

    }

    private void NewEntryView() { 
        firstNameDisplayValue.setText(" ");
        lastNameDisplayValue.setText(" ");
        gpaDisplayValue.setText(" ");

    }     
    private void addToList(String[] info){

       studentCntl.studentList.getStudentList().add(new Student(info));

    }


private void showNew() { 
      NewEntryView();


}

void refreshDisplayWithNewValues(int index) {
        setFieldView();
        this.repaint();


}
```

Comment: The link shows the UIs for both views, when the user clicks 'new entry' from the right view and add it to the table view on the left.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)